# Android - Tor Vulnerabilities with Orfox/Orbot?

Tags: android, vulnerability, tor

What are the vulnerabilities of Orbot and Orfox, when it comes to staying anonymous while on Tor? I have read that some Android apps might transmit in plaintext in some unexpected fashion, while the web Orfox traffic payloads are encrypted as expected. I also read that the cellular network can be the biggest problem.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some links to what you have read, so it gets a bit more concrete? Right now this is a very broad question - basically you are asking in what way is X vulnerable.